# how can I hide like/reblog buttons from a none login tumblr user?

Tags: tumblr

I have my Tumblr account connected to my own domain name.
The issue is that i want Tumbler users will have the option to like or re blogging my posts but when anonymous user that comes from outside the tumblr network (redirect form Google for example )he will not see those buttons

Do you think its possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Tumblr JS or all through API to connect?

Answer (score 1):

Open up your blog > go to 'customize' > scroll down to the very bottom, click 'advanced options' > uncheck the box that says 'Promote Tumblr!'. This will disable the follow iframe from non-tumblr users.

Unfortunately there is no way to tell if a user is logged in (or indeed has an account) or not to hide the 'like' and 'reblog' buttons.

Comment: Technically there is a way to tell if a user is logged in, but its horrible. Disable *Promote Tumblr*. If the page contains the following element,  `<iframe id="tumblr_controls" />`, the visitor is a logged in Tumblr user. If not, the visitor is not logged or anonymous.

Comment: You could also add the following to your CSS to disable the iframe altogether: `iframe#tumblr_controls {display:none !important;` but that means everything is gone... reblog, like, follow, unfollow, dashboard (and others if you use xkit) from the top corner.